# Single script for fadetoggle

Tags: jquery, html

I've been trying to create a slide toggle that hides all toggles when clicking outside the buttons. It's already done. My problem is I need to create script for each button to display and hide the tooltip/content. Is there a way to do this in a single script so that when I add more buttons and contents I don't have to add more scripts? Thanks in advance.

Here is the html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $content = $(".tooltip1").hide();
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".button1")) {
      $content.slideToggle();

    } else {
      $content.slideUp();
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $content = $(".tooltip2").hide();
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".button2")) {
      $content.slideToggle();

    } else {
      $content.slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle1">
  <a class="button1 button" href="#">Button 1</a>
  <p class="tooltip1 tooltip">Tooltip1</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle2">
  <a class="button2 button" href="#">Button 2</a>
  <p class="tooltip2 tooltip">Tooltip2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes certainly

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click",function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("button")) {
      $(".tooltip").slideUp();
    }
  });
  $(".button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
    $(".tooltip").slideUp(); // can test here to not yoyo
    $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
    // or $(this).parent().find(".tooltip").slideToggle(); if not next to link
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle1">
  <a class="button" href="#">Button 1</a>
  <p class="tooltip">Tooltip1</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle2">
  <a class="button" href="#">Button 2</a>
  <p class="tooltip">Tooltip2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I click Button 2, it does not hide the content of Button 1, and viseversa. Also all the contents do not hide when I click outside the buttons.